# how to shutdown firefox using python

Tags: python, subprocess

Hello guys I am having some trouble trying to kill a subprocess.Popen
Indeed what I want is to open a tor window thanks to python, do my stuff and then close the tor window, here is what I did so far :

subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe'])

#do my code

subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe']).terminate()

however it is not working since the tor window is still open at the end of the program

notice that if do :

subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe'])

subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe']).terminate()

without adding any code between this two lines it works perfectly and I can't figure out why.
Anyone can help me on killing this subprocess ?

Comment: If this fails only when there's code between creation and termination, you should be providing a [mre] that has the shortest possible code that _actually has the failure_. And make sure it's correct enough to not be obviously broken on its face (I don't know if you're creating a new instance and terminating the new one in your real program, or only as shorthand in the question, but it's a critical distinction).

Comment: Also, for a web browser specifically there are better ways to kill it than just sending a SIGTERM. Take a look at the command line arguments Firefox has available for process control, running code in the target browser, etc.

Comment: Ok sorry I am just a newbie on this website,

Comment: however even if I put a simple time.sleep() between subprocess.Popen and subprocess.terminate() the browser won't close..

Comment: That makes sense. If you kill the process before it finished connecting to the existing copy of the browser in memory, you prevent it from starting up. By contrast, if it already handed off the instruction to open a new window to the existing copy and excited, it _already exited_, so sending a TERM signal does nothing. As I said before, this is a way modern web browsers are different from most other applications.

Comment: So do you have any idea of how to fix this ? thanks for helping me

Comment: I already gave you my idea, an hour ago. *Take a look at the command line arguments Firefox has available for process control, running code in the target browser, etc.*

Comment: ok thank you I appreciate it

Comment: At a minimum, edit your question to be explicitly about how to shut down a copy of Firefox your script started instead of being about `subprocess.Popen` in general.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are starting two subprocesses. You should try:

```
my_process = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\Myname\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe'])
# your code
my_process.terminate()
```